# PHP MySql Query Missing

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL database and I want to run a query against it from php.

The query is generated by php which is:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (title, link, pubdate, insertdate)
        VALUES ('$title', '$link', '$pubDate', '$date')";
```

This produces the following query

```
INSERT INTO tbluknova (title, link, pubdate, insertdate) 
VALUES (' Through The Keyhole S01E07 Christmas Special.avi {{Gameshow}, {New}} ',
        'http://www.website.ph/wsgi/feed/b1d2793376065c7cec861d156771e162/8854', 
        'Mon, 16 Dec 2013 02:56:35 GMT', 
        '2013-12-16 07:38:20'
)
```

When PHP runs this query their is no entry in the title field.

If I run this query manually, the query works ok, and all fields have the correct entries.

Even though there is no entry showing in the title field, if I run a query searching the 
title field for this entry MySQL finds it !!!!!!!

```
select 
    * 
from tbluknova 
where title LIKE '%Through The Keyhole S01E07 Christmas Special.avi {{Gameshow}, {New}}%'
```

This is driving me crazy.

Thanks for reading and your help

Comment: How do you execute it? mysql, mysqli, PDO? Check the error which is returned for example (for mysql) with mysql_error()

Comment: How are you determining that "*there is no entry in the title field*"?  Perhaps the problem is on data retrieval, not insertion?

Comment: Check if it returns anything when used part of the title string say `LIKE '%Keyhole%'` or similar.

Comment: put backticks(`) aroung each column name, and remove single quotes around date value

Answer (score 0):

**mysqli_real_escape_string** is what you need:

take a look at: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

convert these variables in mysql string as follows then use in query

```
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($title);
  $date = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($date);
  $pubDate = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($pubDate);
  $link = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($link);
```